# Web server keeps displaying Index of / and files (including index.html) returns 404 file not found

Tags: html, .htaccess

There are absolutely no spelling mistakes.

I have index.html in /public_html/ (with necessary .css files etc)

Also in the same folder I have the .htaccess file.

Also to note this was literally working 5 minutes ago, and now my web server is not displaying the index.html or any other file, it just says that it cannot be found with a 404 error message. Also next to the files under the memory size it says 0k, and it says the files were last modified on 31-Dec-1969. What?

What could be going on here?

Comment: What's in the .htaccess file?  Is that trying to redirect to somewhere else?  Are you sure your configuration has the root as /public_html/ ?

Comment: The only thing inside .htaccess is: DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm default.htm index.php index.php3 index.phtml index.php5 index.shtml mwindex.phtml

Comment: Also, how do I check if the configuration has the root as /public_html/? (I'm using cPanel), and to confirm, I am putting everything in /public_html/

Comment: I suggest contacting support. Knowing that there are no spelling issues and htaccess is fine... we cannot help you.

Comment: Why do you have all of those files inside the .htaccess?  I don't think you're supposed to have those there at all.  You should try removing everything except "RewriteBase /"